# Ancient Greek - Adverb functions as Noun

Tags: ancient-greek, noun, adverb, aristotle

Aristotle's Metaphysics, 994a,26-7:

> ἀεὶ γάρ ἐστι **μεταξύ**, ὥσπερ τοῦ εἶναι καὶ μὴ εἶναι γένεσις, οὕτω καὶ τὸ γιγνόμενον τοῦ ὄντος καὶ μὴ ὄντος

Reeve's translation:

> for there is always **an intermediate**, so that as between being and not being there is coming to be, so too the thing that is coming to be is between the thing that is and the thing that is not

How can an adverb function as a noun? I have seen this function in some other instances, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think μεταξύ is functioning as a noun here, but normally as a preposition. Here's a paraphrase to make the syntax clearer:

> ἀεὶ γάρ, ὥσπερ γένεσίς ἐστι μεταξύ τοῦ εἶναι καὶ μὴ εἶναι, οὕτω καὶ τὸ γιγνόμενόν ἐστι μεταξύ τοῦ ὄντος καὶ μὴ ὄντος.

[Tredennick's translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:tlg,0086,025:2:994a):

> For just as "becoming" is always intermediate between being and not-being, so is that which is becoming between what is and what is not.

Comment: LSJ: 3. of Qualities, τὰ μεταξὺ intermediate, i.e. neither good nor bad, Pl.Grg.468a.
Here, it is not functioning as a noun, too? In Metaphysics, however, it does not have an article.

Comment: @AliNikzad The article is required for it to function as a noun. Or put otherwise, with a phrase like τὰ μεταξὺ there's an implied generic noun, "the (things) between", but that's not the case when the article is absent.

Comment: I think "ἐπὶ τὸ κάτω" follows the same rule. Could you please mention an entry in grammar books about the composition of article and adverb?

Comment: @AliNikzad Sure, see Smyth 1153 on the substantival use of the article: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Asmythp%3D1153

Comment: I appreciate your consideration.

Comment: How do you search greek text? I cannot search Greek phrases at all on perseus.

Comment: @Michael16 That's worth a separate question as it's not really related to this one, but the TLG is a good resource: http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/